# My class files inside WEB-INF/classes gets deleted when i load my webapp in webapps folder

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, struts

I am using Tomcat 5, when I start the server and load my app from webapp folder, my JSP loads but **class files inside the `WEB-INF/classes` is being erased automatically**  and when I load the class files it throws this:

[image: this is the error]

My servlets class files are deleting/don't know where it goes.

```
  This is my `web.xml` file inside `WEB-INF/` .classes mapped inside `web.xml` is in `WEB-INF/classes`. All class files inside this is getting erased.

   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>


   <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
   <description>
    Welcome to Tomcat
   </description>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>HelloForm</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>HelloForm</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/HelloForm</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
   <servlet-class>Upload</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Upload</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/Upload</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>Getapplicants</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>Getapplicants</servlet-class>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Getapplicants</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/Getapplicants</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>First_round_selected</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>First_round_selected</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>First_round_selected</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/First_round_selected</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Second_round_selected</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>Second_round_selected</servlet-class>
 </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Second_round_selected</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/Second_round_selected</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>


   
   </web-app>
```

**Stuck with this:**

**`Upload.java`:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
// Extend HttpServlet class
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {

// Method to handle GET method request.
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
  response)throws ServletException, IOException {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  String first_name=request.getParameter("first_name");
  String last_name=request.getParameter("last_name");
  String email=request.getParameter("email");
  String phone_number=request.getParameter("phone_number");
  String experience =request.getParameter("experience");

  try{
  Connection 
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/interview"
  ,"root","
   ");  
     Statement stmt=con.createStatement(); 
     int rows=stmt.executeUpdate("insert into applicants 
     values('"+first_name+"','"+last_name+"','"+email+"',"+
     Long.valueOf(phone_number
                 )+","+Integer.valueOf(experience)+")");      
                con.close();
              out.print("Added Sucessfully");


          }catch(Exception e){out.print(e);}   
           }


        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
         response)
           throws ServletException, IOException {

         doGet(request, response);
          }
         }
```

Comment: post your web.xml and servlet code

Comment: edited in main with web.xml

Comment: POST java code also, only Upload is required

Comment: posted with Upload java

Comment: <servlet-class>Upload</servlet-class> here you should mention the fully qualified name of your class like <servlet-class>packagename.Upload</servlet-class>

Comment: ya.....i compiled these files without a package name.

Comment: Answer updated..

Answer (score 0):

As you said you are using `tomcat 5` and it support till `servlet 2.5`. But you are using `servlet 3.0`

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0"
```

see the details below

[image]

There are two solutions: **Upgrade your tomcat or use servlet 2.5**

**Servlet 2.5 deployment descriptor**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          version="2.5">
</web-app>
```

Comment: ya but when i compress the class files inside a jar , put on lib and used every thing is working fine......but files inside the WEB-INF/classes are getting lost/deleted.

Comment: is your Jar working? the files are getting deleted after the creation of jar correct? are you using any build tool? please post how you are building the files and create the jar

Comment: i builded a jar using these class files in cmd prompt and i had put the jar on WEB-INF/lib .that time my class files are mapping with the class inside the jar correctly.but when i put seperately the class files(without jar) inside WEB-INF/classes the class files get deleted.

Comment: Did you create the application in tomcat webapps directory?

Comment: i am working with mickey framework developed by our company.....It is bundled with tomcat 5 version.I had put my app in webapps directory of framework,but tomcat is the one which deploys it.

Comment: you are able to create the jar, then why you are afraid about the classfiles in webinf..

Comment: did you check the webapps/build directory?

Comment: It is working with jars but i want to know the reason why the class files gets deleted.....There should be a reason behind it na....that's i asked...

Comment: found thi. please check...https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=117870

Answer (score 0):

try to put your servlet class to src/main/java folder. Also I recomend you to put it in package like com.servlet or something. Then in the web.xml fill the path to you class like this: package.MyServlet

Answer (score 0):

If you are using compiling output to `WEB-INF/classes` then it erases this folder each time you compile the application. To fix this you should change the folder used for compiler output.

If you ever seen this guide [How to Create a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.wst.webtools.doc.user/topics/twcreprj.html?cp=86_0_1_1) then you will realize that output folder is created outside the web content.

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.stardust.docs.wst/html/wst-integration/images/set-build-path.png))</sub>

This allows to store/clean compiled files during development. Finally when you deploy your application to the server the content should be copied to `WEB-INF/classes` automatically.

Since class files are under `WEB-INF` folder they are not accessible from  outside the web and you can safely browse the content.